# Commenting in Laravel blade error "Something went wrong"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to wrap my head around Laravel.

I am commenting code out for later use. 
My problem occurs, when I have a snippet of code commented out, but the code is not "true".

Example for what works for me:

```
<head>
    <!-- {{ HTML::script('js/scrollTo.js'); }} -->
    {{ HTML::style('css/style.css'); }}
</head>

<head>
    <!-- Foo {{ HTML::script('js/scrollTo.js'); }} Bar -->
    {{ HTML::style('css/style.css'); }}
</head>
```

What doesn't work for me:

```
<head>
    <!-- {{ } HTML::script('js/scrollTo.js'); }} -->
    {{ HTML::style('css/style.css'); }}
</head>
```

Whenever I put something within the blade tags, the system makes an error.
Why I would even do this, i am not sure. But what I don't understand is why the system makes an error when the tag is commentet out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Blade Comments:

```
<head>
    {{-- {{ } HTML::script('js/scrollTo.js'); }} --}}
    {{ HTML::style('css/style.css'); }}
</head>
```

Comment: If this is what you needed then why are you asking about the behavior and not about how to comment out blade?

Comment: Also, though this way of commenting out blade is possible, the conventional way is to append the '--' but not to add a whole new pair of '{{ }}'s. Just: `{{-- } HTML::script('js/scrollTo.js'); --}}` is enough.

Answer (score 2):

The Blade tags still get rendered, even within an HTML comment (Blade is not a HTML parser, so it has no clue what `<!--` means). Your resulting view code is going to be:

```
<!-- <?php } HTML::script('js/scrollTo.js'); ?> -->
```

which is a parse error. You can use Blade comments:

```
{{-- {{ } HTML::script('js/scrollTo.js'); }} --}}
```

but the real question is why not fix the slightly invalid code in the first place?

Comment: You are right, if the code is as slightly invalid as this, that would make sense. But this was to get an understanding of why it doens't work.

Comment: I bet he just created an error to show that it will have a spasm.